# Upper bound for $\Gamma(x+y)$

Tags: functions, inequality, special-functions, approximation

Let $x, y \geq 1$ be two real numbers.

I am wondering if one can get an upper bound for $\Gamma(x+y)$ in terms of $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)$?

Any references or ideas are very appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). In particular, we have the following relation:
$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)=B(x,y)\Gamma(x+y).$$
Hence, your problem reduces to finding bounds (or asymptotics) for the Beta function (see the section *Approximations*).